# Android game performance viewer

Tags: android

How I can scan the performance of my game?

I use OpenGL ES in my game, but sometimes, when many enemies on the screen, it will lagg a little. (15-20 enemy + 7-8 rockets, etc)

what is the best way to see what is the "non best" algorithm on my code? (performance viewer, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [traceview](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to profile your application, which will show you the amount of tile and number of calls to methods in your program.

Answer (score 2):

For the CPU, [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) is awesome. For the GPU, you're screwed (see my question about that). There are some GPU-specific packages, like for the Adreno GPU, but generally, OpenGL ES seems devoid of any general-purpose GPU profiling options.